# Docker-Compose command for redis-stack-server persistence

Tags: docker-compose, redis, redis-stack-server

If I use the default *redis docker image* configured with docker compose as such:

```
redis-storage:
  image: redis:7.0
  container_name: 'redis-storage'
  command: ["redis-server", "--save", "1200", "32", "--loglevel", "warning"]
  volumes:
    - redis-storage-data:/data
```

it starts up fine and writes to disk every 20 minutes if at least 32 changes.

But if I use the same `command` with `image: redis/redis-stack-server:latest` it appears to start okay, but it really goes into protected mode and becomes inaccessible. Commenting out the command, all works fine.

What is the correct `command` in docker-compose format that will allows altering the default save-to-disk parameters?

(Also tried alternative syntax: `command: redis-server --save 1200 32`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Working solution for `docker-compose schema '3.8'`:

```
redis-stack-svc:
  image: redis/redis-stack-server:latest
  # use REDIS_ARGS for redis-stack-server instead of command arguments
  environment:
    - REDIS_ARGS=--save 1200 32
  volumes:
    - my-redis-data:/data
```

Not easy to find a clear, non-conflicting example. And something of an historical bug.

For `redis-stack-server` (when not using a local `redis-stack.conf` file mounted to the container) configuration for the underlying redis can be passed in via the `REDIS_ARGS` environment variable instead of directly to the command. (There are also environment vars for the stack modules, such as `REDISJSON_ARGS`, etc.

However '**save**' is particularly fussy. It expects two arguments `(seconds, changes)` but most configuration parameters expect one. Some forms of quoting the arguments would make it look like one argument, and the [underlying argument parser](https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/2366) would either be ignored or report '*wrong number of arguments*' and put the server into protected mode.

For `save`, you can also specify several conditionals. For example, the default is:

`save 3600 1 300 100 60 10000`

(Save after 1hr if 1 write, after 5min if 100 writes, after 60 sec if 10000 writes)

For the original `redis` container, you can specify this in docker-compose as command line arguments using the following format:

```
redis-storage:
  image: redis:7.0
  command: ["redis-server", "--save", "3600", "1", "300", "100", "60", "10000"]
  volumes:
    - my-redis-data:/data
```

However, the underlying argument parsing logic creates a problem for `redis-stack`
Both of these formats will be parsed incorrectly:

```
  # (valid syntax but ignored...'save' is actually set to 'nil')
  environment: 
    - REDIS_ARGS=--save 3600 1 300 100 60 10000
  
  # ('invalid number of arguments', server not started) 
  environment:
    - REDIS_ARGS="--save 3600 1 300 100 60 10000"
```

The correct syntax is obscure:

```
  # (using non-default values here to validate the behavior) 
  environment:
    - REDIS_ARGS=--save 3602 1 --save 302 100 --save 62 10000
```

If you `docker exec` into the running container and invoke `redis-cli CONFIG GET save` it will return:

```
root@f45860:/data# redis-cli CONFIG GET save
1) "save"
2) "3602 1 302 100 62 10000"
```

There is also an alternative compose syntax example in the
[redis developer docs](https://developer.redis.com/develop/java/spring/redis-om/redis-om-spring-hash/)

```
  environment:
    - REDIS_ARGS:--save 20 1
```

but compose schema 3.8 will complain (the example uses schema 3.9)